# Three.js, Camera rotation around a point

Tags: camera, rotation, three.js, quaternions

I'm trying to make a camera rotation and zoom around a point.
I don't want to use **THREE.TrackBallControls** because as i see, it only modify the fov when zooming, it is not what i want.

I'm using this simple equation : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Equations_in. To compute a point on the sphere, this point will be the position of the camera.

In three.js

```
var point = new THREE.Vector3(
    radius * Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
    radius * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi),
    radius * Math.cos(phi)
);
point.add(center);
```

To manipulate it, i use :

- left mouse, for rotation : x coord === theta and y coord === phi
- middle mouse, for zooming : zoom in/out === radius

It doesn't work well, especially for 'phi' rotation, maybe because it's define between 0 and PI.

Maybe there is a better solution using **Quaternion.Slerp** ?

edit :

My camera :

```
aspectRatio = container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -aspectRatio * viewSize / 2, aspectRatio * viewSize / 2, viewSize / 2, -viewSize / 2, -10, 10 );
camera.position.x = 0.004;
camera.position.y = 0.004;
camera.position.z = 0.004;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))
scene.add(camera);
```

My OrbitControls :

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls ( camera );
controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
controls.keyPanSpeed = 0.8;
controls.noZoom = false;
controls.noPan = false;
```

when using left mouse (rotation) the camera.position change.

when using middle mouse (zoom) the camera.position is still the same.

check made in the render function :

```
function render() {
  // update camera controls
  controls.update();
  console.log(camera.position);
  // actually render the scene
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Trackballcontrols do move the camera without changing its FOV. For euler angles maths controls you can have a look at OrbitControls that seems to be what you need ?

Comment: Yes i try it. I have the same issue : when zooming the camera.position is always the same (that why i think it just change the FOV)

Comment: have you got an example ?

Comment: The equation you copied uses a different coordinate system. In three.js, y-axis is up.

Comment: i added same details in my question. Ok, that why the equations are different in OrbitControl.

    offset.x = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
    offset.y = radius * Math.cos( phi );
    offset.z = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );

Comment: You did not previously mention that you are using `OrthographicCamera`. Look at `OrthographicTrackballControls.js`.

Comment: yes, i use OrthographicTrackballControls.js in the first place, but this is the same. I just see a object.zoom attribute, in OrthographicTrackballControls